# django no reverse match form action don't work

Tags: django, linux, python-2.7

11 and python 2.7, and i have a error while rendering a view. Is when load the html in action form url don't work, i don't know why.

Any suggestions?

The url:

```
url(r'^admin/user_list/(?P<user_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.admin_zone_edit_user, name='edit_users'),
```

The html:

```
 {% extends 'admin/baseadmin.html' %} 
 {% load staticfiles %}
 {% block content %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div ><form id="login" action="{% url 'admin_zone_edit_user' %}" method  ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>

  </form></div>
  {% endblock %}
```

And the error, no reverse match.

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/user_list/3/edit/

Reverse for 'admin_zone_edit_user' not found. 'admin_zone_edit_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user_list/3/edit/
Django Version:     1.11.11
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'admin_zone_edit_user' not found. 'admin_zone_edit_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/rokanas/rummi',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/rokanas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Mon, 9 Apr 2018 18:52:37 +0000
Error during template rendering
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name in the `url` template tag is incorrect. According to your url definition, the template code should be:

```
action="{% url 'edit_users' user_id %}"
```

Edited to add `user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Your url doesn't work because your view expect `user_id`, also url name is wrong. URL tag works as follow
`{% url '<url_name>' <expected_value/s> %}`